# Autofac ViewRegistrationSource doesn't work with _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

I am currently using Autofac for Dependency Injection.

I am having trouble getting injected to work with my BaseViewPage and my _Layout.cshtml. I always end up getting the following error:

```
object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

However, no problems in any of the other view, partial or otherwise.

My base page looks like this:

```
public abstract class NTouchWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel> {
    public IWebSettings WebSettings { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the following in my Status.cs

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<WebSettings>().As<IWebSettings>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterSource(new ViewRegistrationSource());
var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

In my _Layout.cshtml I am simply using

```
@WebSettings.Version
```

and it **object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Per the documentation](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#enable-property-injection-for-view-pages):

> **Due to an issue with ASP.NET MVC internals, dependency injection is not available for Razor layout pages.** Razor views will work, but layout pages won’t.